# How to Create a Globally Available Folder with Modules in Python on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, path, macos-catalina

I have a folder with a few python files (modules) that I want to be globally accessible on MacOS Catalina.

On Windows, I just moved the folder to the python path under `Lib/site-packages/` but I can't seem to find a way to do that on MacOS.

Here is my file structure:

```
myfolder
    - __init__.py
    - file1.py
    - file2.py
```

and I want to access those modules in my python scripts like this:

```py
from myfolder.file1 import func
from myfolder.file2 import func2
```

I tried adding the folder to the path like this

```
# ~/.zprofile
export PATH=/Users/username/dev/myfolder
```

but when running the python script, this error would be thrown: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myfolder'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to export the folder that contains that folder I want to be globally accessible (`myfolder`) as the `PYTHONPATH`:

```
# ~/.zprofile
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/myusername/dev
```

Here is the folder structure:

```
- dev
    - myfolder
        - __init__.py
        - file1.py
        - file2.py
```

and here is how I can access those modules in any python script on my machine:

```py
from myfolder.file1 import func
from myfolder.file2 import func2
```